# Looking for something in json file then trying something else if it doesnt work

Tags: php, json, parsing, steam-web-api

Im getting json files from a site and i want it to find which ever one gets the file and use that one. Im using the $_GET Method too. There are 2 ways of getting the same file but they both require an id or a custom url from steam.

My url example: www.mysite.com?id=123123123

2 ways of getting json file:

- http://steamcommunity.com/id/ID/inventory/json/730/2
- http://steamcommunity.com/CUSTOMURL/76561198051643107/inventory/json/730/2

How im decoding it:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$url = "http://steamcommunity.com/id/".$id."/inventory/json/730/2";
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$playerinfo = json_decode($content, true);
$InventoryStatus = $playerinfo['success'];
```

Comment: What's the problem ? the code is not working ?

Comment: @borracciaBlu I cant find out to make it so it tries one of the urls and sees if it gives you a json and if it doesnt it will try the other one and if not it will return something else

Comment: Is there a specific element you're looking for in the JSON that you can base your return on?

Comment: Use an if() statement.

Comment: @BuzzotheSplitter Its different for everyone...

Comment: @mcon Im returing on a different statement, i just want to get the one that returns a json file.

Answer (score 0):

some ref

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$handlers =array(
    'getByJson','getByDB','getBySomething'
);
$result = array('handler'=>'','data'=>'');
```

then call $handlers

```
foreach($handlers as $m){
    $methodResult = call_user_func($m,$id);
    if($methodResult !==false){
        $result = array('handler'=>$m, 'data' => $methodResult) ;
        break;
    }
}
```

handler something like this

```
function getByJson($id){
    $url = "http://steamcommunity.com/id/".$id."/inventory/json/730/2";
    $string = file_get_contents($url);
    $isJson =is_string($string) && is_object(json_decode($string)) && (json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE) ? true : false;
    if($isJson){
       $playerinfo = json_decode($content, true);
       return $playerinfo['success'];
    }

    return false;
}

function getByDB($id){
     // get $result

        if(condition){
            return $result
        }
        return false;

}

function getBySomething($id){
         // get $result

        if(condition){
            return $result
        }
        return false;
}
```